# Laravel Voyager - Filter Subcategory upon selecting Category

Tags: laravel, filter, relationship, voyager

I am using Laravel Voyager admin panel.

I have a 'products' table where PRODUCT has parent SUBCATEGORY and CATEGORY. I have also **made these relationships**: '**product-subcategory**' and '**product-category**'.

So, when I want to add new product, I can choose CATEGORY and SUBCATEGORY from dropdown.

[image: choosing categories]

The problem is, **SUBCATEGORY dropdown shows all of the subcategories**:

[image]

I want see the **SUBCATEGORIES only from the CATEGORY I choose**. (like we get the column names of specified MODEL(for referencing) when we create relationships in voyager)

The reason I want this is to prevent adding product under wrong Category and Subcategory.

Is there a way to achive this? Should I use some JSON in the 'Optional Details' field?

Comment: How do you get the subcategories in the controller ?

Comment: @Maraboc, Snapshots are taken from Voyager admin panel. I made relationships for Category and Subcategory and set Category and Subcategory names to show in the Voyager BREAD and reference id to store in the table.
So, When I add product, the BREAD shows Category and Subcategory Names instead of their id. Didn't have to make any controller for that.